# Mi aplicación WPF no se ejecuta en otros ordenadores

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, publish

He creado una aplicación WPF que contiene controles de usuario, una librería de estilos, imágenes(PNG) y clases. Al instalarla y ejecutarla funciona perfectamente en mi ordenador, pero al ejecutarla en otro ordenador la instala pero al intentar abrirla no funciona y no da ningún tipo de mensaje de error, en el administrador de tareas se abre y se cierra rapidamente. He probado dos ordenadores diferentes ambos con windows10 x64.

He probado a publicarla con clickonce y con MSIX packaging tool usando Visual Studio 2019 community y utilizando la extensión microsoft blend. He probado con las opciones de x64 y x86,  juntas y por separado, así como any CPU, también mencionar que en el administrador de configuración no me deja marcar la pestaña de implementar, no se si tendrá algo que ver.

También decir que he intentado instalar el .net framework runtime correspondiente (en este caso 4.7.2) en los ordenadores de destino y en el de origen y no me deja instalarlo porque dice que ya hay una versión superior instalada, asumo que debería funcionar igualmente dado que la única versión superior disponible es la 4.8 y en el ordenador de origen si que funciona a pesar de no dejarme instalar el .net 4.7.2, al igual que en los ordenadores de destino, asi que, asumo que ese no es el problema.

He probado a publicar una aplicación mas sencilla y funciona perfectamente tanto en el ordenador de origen como en el de destino.

Adjunto una pequeña descripción de lo que hace la aplicación por si aportase alguna información útil:

Se trata de una aplicación de escritorio que calcula esfuerzos, contiene barras de herramientas con botones, en función del botón que pulses abre un control de usuario u otro, estos controles de usuario contienen un grid formado por 4 columnas que contienen:
una imagen, un canvas, y varios labels y cajas de texto y un boton(calcular), al pulsar el botón calcular obtiene los valores de las cajas de texto, realiza el calculo de esfuerzos, los muestra en las cajas de texto correspondientes y pinta una serie de líneas en el canvas que constituyen el diagrama de esfuerzos.

El proyecto tiene 4 carpetas:
-Imágenes
-Clases
-Controles de usuario
-Diccionario/libreria de estilos que utilizo únicamente para los botones.

Se agradece cualquier ayuda, estoy sin ideas en cuanto a que intentar, si estáis considerando darle voto negativo o cerrar la preguntar por favor indicarme porque para que pueda editarla.

Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! en el administrador de tareas el programa se abre y se cierra? consideraste agregar un log? se conecta a alguna base de datos? podemos tirar mil ideas mas... pero son solo conjeturas.. intentaste compilar otro programa mas corto y mandarlo a ver si el problema esta en otro lado? faltara una dll?

Comment: He probado una aplicación mas sencilla y si que funciona correctamente. Las dll necesarias las instala el .net framework runtime correspondiente cierto? , no se conecta a ninguna base de datos, en el administrador de tareas se abre y acto y se cierra rápidamente, voy a buscar como agregar un log a ver si me da alguna información, si es que básicamente lo que necesitaba era eso, ideas para probar porque no tengo ni idea que es lo que puede estar fallando o como encontrarlo, muchas gracias.

Comment: yo lo que intentaría sería gestionar las excepciones para lanzar un código de error. Wpf es un poco especial en cuanto a las excepciones, pero se pueden gestionar a nivel global para lanzar un error en caso de que se produzca alguna

Answer (score 1):

Vale, por si a alguien le sirviese, he encontrado el problema, a la hora de establecer  la ruta de acceso a las imágenes yo escribía:

```
<Image Source="C:\Users\ramon\source\repos\Calculadora de Vigas\Imagenes\DiagramasCanvas\DiagMApoyada.PNG" />
```

Esto provocaba que en la generación del ejecutable no incluyese las imágenes como parte del proyecto, pero si la dirección, infiero que por ese motivo si funcionaba en el ordenador de origen y no en el de destino, la solución era así de simple:

```
<Image  Source="/Calculadora deVigas;component/Imagenes/DiagramasCanvas/DiagMApoyada.PNG"/>
```